# Отображение сообщения с почты на сайте через PHP

Tags: php, opencart, email, imap

Есть сайт на opencart, есть две почты, с которых отправляются уведомления на почты заказчиков. По мимо всего прочего, эти уведомления видны и в личном кабинете пользователя. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы собщение которое отправленно пользователем через кнопку "ответить" например, с mail.ru отображалось на сайте рядом с тем сообщением, на которое он ответил ?

чтобы было более-менее понятно, немного о структуре:

---

Менеджер: 
Уважаемый пользователь, у вас был изменен пароль на 123456!
Ответ: 
спасибо!
                                                     29.08.2017

---

Менеджер:
Уважаемый пользователь, вам доступен этот товар!
Ответ: 
Спасибо!

---

еще один пример, уже из форумов, например, когда отвечаешь на чей либо комментарий(сохраняется в виде иерархии комментариев, показывается, на какой комментарий был добавлен ответ)

нужно сделать примерно так же, только чтобы эти "ответы на комментарии" можно было оставить с почты, и отобразить их на сайте...
знаю, что вроде как через imap можно получить массив с сообщениями с меткой, например, UNSEEN, но что делать дальше и как их отсортировать и отобразить-без понятия...

```
$user  = 'example@gmail.com';

$pass = '123';

$connect = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',$user, $pass);
if ($connect) echo 'Successful'; else {echo 'Failed'; die;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно разделить получение комментариев с почты и их отображение.

У вас должна быть таблица в СуБД которая хранит все комментарии, и уже из неё должны отображаться комментарии для клиентов.

Чтобы отображались комментарии с почты, - нужно настроить автоматическую загрузку комментариев с почты в имеющуюся таблицу в СуБД. Для этого нужно написать скрипт со следующей логикой:

- Подключиться по IMAP.
- Найти сообщения с меткой UNSEEN.
- Итеративно обойти сообщения, получить текст и сохранить в СуБД, снять метку UNSEEN.

Скрипт нужно настроить на автоматический запуск в какой-то интервал времени (например через crontab), при этом ограничить возможность запуска более одного экземпляра скрипта (например через блокировки, или проверку в начале скрипта, что он еще не запущен).